# How to hide handles in QSplitter widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is it possible to completely hide handles from QSplitter widget? I've tried to hide() them but it doesn't work — handles are still on the screen and isVisible() reporting false.

QSplitter::setHandleWidth doesn't work as expected — it doesn't hide handles when calling it with 0.

Answer (score 1):

The inability to set a zero-width handle seems odd and might be considered a bug - but then again why would you want to? You won't be able to grab a zero-width handle so it seems to be that you really want to use a vertical/horizontal layout.

Comment: I want to “lock” layout, like locking toolbars feature in many apps.

Comment: Try;

   handle->splitter(num)->setEnabled(false)

Comment: I've tried it, it disables handles but no hides them unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How bout subclassing QSplitter and overriding paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) to block actual painting of the widget?

Comment: It looks like QSplitter subclassing is the only method.

Answer (score 0):

Use QSplitter::handleWidth(1).
I tried with handleWidth(0) but it seems that the minimum accepted width is 1

Answer (score 0):

setting the image to a non-exists image seems working

`self.splitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle {  image: url(images/notExists.png); }")`

Answer (score 0):

Calling QSplitter::setHandleWidth with zero works now. 
If you are using designer, setting handle width property to zero does the trick.